# Agrupar registro por columna incluyendo valores NULL

Tags: sql-server

Tengo este script

```
SELECT 
n.Conteo,  MAX(d.IdPaciente) OVER(PARTITION BY d.IdPaciente ORDER BY d.IdPaciente  )IdPaciente , IdPaciente, d.FechaAnalitica, d.GlucosaPre, d.Sodio, d.Calcio
FROM 
    ##Numeros n
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY pt.IdPaciente ASC) row,
        pt.IdPaciente, FechaAnalitica, GlucosaPre,Sodio, Calcio
    FROM ANA_BIOQUIMICA inner join ##PAC_ID_TEMP pt 
    on ANA_BIOQUIMICA.IdPaciente = pt.IdPaciente 
)d
 ON n.Conteo = d.row
where n.Tabla = 'ANA_BIOQUIMICA'
order by d.IdPaciente,  n.Conteo
```

Este es el script real...como se muestra .... no existe un filtro where, ya que la lista resultante, se debe crear para un conjunto de valores de IdPaciente, en este caso es donde el script no agrupa los null para cada codigo De IdPaciente... sino los coloca juntos al inicio de la lista.

Adicionalmente comento lo siguiente. La tabla ##Numeros contiene el conteo de registros max por paciente... en el caso que estoy planteando hay dos pacientes el código 2450 y el código 38

Por lo que la lista resultante debería ser de 88 registros...ya que la tabla ##Numeros para la tabla ANA_BIOQUIMICA esta configurada para ese valor

Entonces el left join con ##Numeros , sirve para completar con registros null, los que le hagan falta a cada código de paciente.

entonces deberían haber 44 registros para cada código de IdPaciente...  para el caso del código 38 11 registros con valores y 33 con valores null

Comment: haz probado ponerle el order by al final de toda tu consulta? algo asi.   `SELECT n.n, MAX(d.IdPaciente) OVER() IdPaciente, d.FechaAnalitica, d.GlucosaPre, d.Sodio, d.Calcio FROM Numeros n LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY IdPaciente ASC) r, IdPaciente, FechaAnalitica, GlucosaPre, Sodio, Calcio FROM ANA_BIOQUIMICA
WHERE IdPaciente = 2450 ) d ON n.n = d.r  order by IdPaciente`

Comment: mira por favor [tour] y [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sé realmente si lo siguiente responde tu pregunta:

```
SELECT  n.Conteo,  
    n.IdPaciente, 
    d.FechaAnalitica, 
    d.GlucosaPre, 
    d.Sodio, 
    d.Calcio
    FROM (SELECT    Conteo,
            IdPaciente,
            FROM ##PAC_ID_TEMP
            CROSS JOIN ##Numeros 
            WHERE Tabla = 'ANA_BIOQUIMICA'
        ) n
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT IdPaciente,
                       FechaAnalitica, 
                       GlucosaPre, 
                       Sodio, 
                       Calcio,
                       ROW_NUMBER() (OVER PARTITION BY IdPaciente ORDER BY IdPaciente) AS Conteo
                FROM ANA_BIOQUIMICA
                ORDER BY IdPaciente
        ) A
        ON A.IdPaciente = n.IdPaciente  
        AND A.Conteo = n.Conteo
    ORDER BY n.IdPaciente,  n.Conteo
```

Conceptualmente, al menos, lo que hacemos es generar una tabla de números para cada paciente esto entiendo debería generate los 44 registros para cada paciente, luego simplemente hay que hacer un `LEFT` a `ANA_BIOQUIMICA` con un `ROW_NUMBER()` para hacer match con `Conteo`.

Comment: Estupendo... esto exactamente lo que necesitaba ... Gracias.